# How to fix NetworkManager-dispatcher script permission denied error?

Tags: permissions, networkmanager, rocky-linux

I've got a fully updated RockyLinux 9.2 server, where I have a couple of network services running via Systemd.

Following the instructions such as from [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/725928) and [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/NetworkManager#Network_services_with_NetworkManager_dispatcher), I created a shell script that's triggered whenever a particular network interface is online, which runs `systemctl restart` on those services. This could be useful to have those services restart after a network outage.

So, I've created `/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/10-restart-network-services.sh` with the following contents which restarts the [`zerotier-one`](https://www.zerotier.com) service:

```
DEVICE=${1}
STATE=${2}

if [ "$DEVICE" = "[interface name]" ]; then
   if [ "$STATE" = "up" ]; then
      /usr/bin/systemctl restart zerotier-one.service
   fi
fi
```

Where I replaced `interface name` with the actual interface name I get from `ifconfig`.

When I tested the script by manually unplugging the ethernet cable from that network interface and reconnecting, or just by rebooting, I see the following errors in the `systemctl status NetworkManager-dispatcher` logs:

```
Oct 15 15:26:31 [hostname] nm-dispatcher[2433]: /etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/10-restart-network-services.sh: line 6: /usr/bin/systemctl: Permission denied
Oct 15 15:26:31 [hostname] nm-dispatcher[2353]: req:12 'up' [interface name], "/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/10-restart-network-services.sh": complete: failed with Script '/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/10-restart-network-services.sh'  exited with status 126.
```

Looks like my script is successfully started, but the `systemctl restart` command got a "Permission denied" error.

Here's what I've tried so far:

1. Use `sudo chmod 700` permissions on the script.
2. Use `sudo chmod 755` permissions on the script.
3. Both the plain `systemctl` command and with its full path `/usr/bin/systemctl` in the shell script. When the script only has the `systemctl` command without its full path, the error is command not found instead of permission denied.
4. Run `restorecon /etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/10-restart-network-services.sh`.

None of them solved the problem.

Any suggestions? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue (with a different service) and the short answer is SELinux is preventing the NetworkManager dispatcher script from restarting zerotier-one.service. You'll need to create a new SELinux policy to allow the dispatcher SELinux file "type" to access the zerotier-one service "type". Disclaimer: I couldn't get this working, so take my advice with a grain of salt. I am new to SELinux and learned all this while troubleshooting my own issue.

For the long answer, read on:

You can confirm the root cause by searching for dispatcher SELinux errors with:

`ausearch -m AVC,USER_AVC,SELINUX_ERR,USER_SELINUX_ERR | grep dispatcher`

You can also set SELinux to permissive then restart NetworkManager to confirm if that allows your dispatcher script to work.

```
setenforce 0
getenforce
service NetworkManager restart
setenforce 1
getenforce
```

An SELinux file "type" is basically just an SELinux label for a group of files that are allowed to perform actions on each other, assuming the regular file permissions allow it first.

You can run `ll -Z` to see the SELinux context for a file, the string ending in _t is the file type descriptor like etc_t or bin_t.

```
ll -Z /
dr-xr-xr-x.   2 root root system_u:object_r:mnt_t:s0            6 Mar 25  2022 afs
lrwxrwxrwx.   1 root root system_u:object_r:bin_t:s0            7 Mar 25  2022 bin -> usr/bin
dr-xr-xr-x.   5 root root system_u:object_r:boot_t:s0        4096 Mar 23 22:54 boot
```

The SELinux permissions (MAC) are separate from the typical rwx permissions (DAC) that are associated with files, and the SELinux permissions are checked afterwards only if the basic DAC permissions allow the user action first.

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/security-enhanced_linux/sect-security-enhanced_linux-working_with_selinux-selinux_contexts_labeling_files

It's designed to prevent a compromised process from wreaking havoc on your entire filesystem. With SELinux a compromised process can only wreak havoc on files that share the same file type, which should just be any the files the process needs in order to function.

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/9/html-single/using_selinux/index#introduction-to-selinux_getting-started-with-selinux

Most of the time you need to just modify the SELinux policy to allow one file type to access another type, but systemctl is a little different. It's not ideal to give the dispatcher script access to systemctl, because then it would have control over anything systemctl has control over, which is your whole system. So there is another SELinux class called "service" which allows a script to call a specific systemd service, which in your case is zerotier-one.service.

I ended up finding a workaround for my needs but I gave your use case a shot by trying to restart the atd.service with a NM dispatcher script, but unfortunately I wasn't able to get it to work.

There are tools audit2why and audit2allow which help you write SELinux policies based on SELinux failures in the audit logs, but people seem to advise against using them. I noticed they did not suggest using the service class like you're supposed to for systemd. But I found audit2allow helpful for creating a basic SELinux policy template file that I then customized.

I also tried blindly following all the automated recommendations from audit2allow and each time after modifying the policy a new failure occurred, and eventually the audit2why tool said "yeah this action should have been allowed with your current policy, idk what to tell you":

```
# ausearch -i | awk '/dispatcher/ && /systemctl/' | tail -5 | audit2why
type=AVC msg=audit(03/25/2024 15:29:17.520:748) : avc:  denied  { map } for 
pid=37569 comm=systemctl path=/usr/bin/systemctl dev="dm-0" ino=402765363 
scontext=system_u:system_r:NetworkManager_dispatcher_t:s0 
tcontext=system_u:object_r:systemd_systemctl_exec_t:s0 tclass=file permissive=0

Was caused by:
            Unknown - would be allowed by active policy
            Possible mismatch between this policy and the one under which the audit message was generated.

            Possible mismatch between current in-memory boolean settings vs. permanent ones.
```

So unfortunately this is as far as I got before I gave up. But I'll share the steps I performed to make a custom SELinux policy because it is a little hard to figure out. Hopefully you can get it to work, and please let me know how you did it if you do. I am running Almalinux 9.3 which should be almost the exact same as Rocky linux, since they're both clones of Redhat.

#### SELinux custom policy creation

SELinux service policy: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/selinux_users_and_administrators_guide/chap-security-enhanced_linux-systemd_access_control

General policy documentation: https://selinuxproject.org/page/PolicyStatements

Helpful guide: https://billauer.co.il/selinux-policy-module-howto.html

Create custom module package based on automated recommendations (this won't change the SELinux policy until you import it)

`grep dispatcher /var/log/audit/audit.log | tail -5 | audit2allow -M custom_NM_dispatcher_policy`

Review the new module:

`cat custom_NM_dispatcher_policy.te`

Output:

```
module custom_NM_dispatcher_policy 1.0;

require {
        type NetworkManager_dispatcher_t;
        type systemd_systemctl_exec_t;
        class file getattr;
}

#============= NetworkManager_dispatcher_t ==============
allow NetworkManager_dispatcher_t systemd_systemctl_exec_t:file getattr;
```

As you can see audit2allow is recommending we allow the getattr action for NetworkManager_dispatcher_t on files with systemd_systemctl_exec_t file type, but this will not work. After I created and imported the recommended custom policy it failed on the next required action, and kept failing each time I added the next recommended action until it eventually said "unknown".

That's when I did more research and learned about using the :service class instead of :file for systemd services. I followed the documentation as far as I can tell but my dispatcher script still fails, not sure why.

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/selinux_users_and_administrators_guide/chap-security-enhanced_linux-systemd_access_control

Here is how I modified the file that audit2allow generated to try to allow access to the atd service:

Locate atd service file

```
find / -iname atd.service
/usr/lib/systemd/system/atd.service
```

Get SELinux file type (ending in _t)

```
ll -Z /usr/lib/systemd/system/atd.service
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root system_u:object_r:crond_unit_file_t:s0 274 Oct 14  2022 /usr/lib/systemd/system/atd.service
```

Customize the policy.te file

`vim custom_NM_dispatcher_policy.te`

```
module custom_NM_dispatcher_policy 1.0;

# reference pre-defined SELinux types and service actions
require {
        type NetworkManager_dispatcher_t;
        type crond_unit_file_t;
        class service { start }; # the documentation says "restart" action only requires start permissions
}

#============= NetworkManager_dispatcher_t ==============
# Allow NetworkManager dispatcher script to restart atd service
allow NetworkManager_dispatcher_t crond_unit_file_t : service { start };
```

Install SElinux dev tools to get the Makefile, which we need in order to build the .pp file
The setools-console provides helpful tools like sesearch to search current SELinux policy actions

`dnf -y install policycoreutils-devel setools-console`

Find SELinux Makefile (most likely at /usr/share/selinux/devel/Makefile)

`find / -iname Makefile`

Link it to current directory

`ln -s /usr/share/selinux/devel/Makefile`

Build .te file into binary .pp file (overwrite the .pp file that audit2allow generated)

`make custom_NM_dispatcher_policy.pp`

```
Compiling targeted custom_NM_dispatcher_policy module
Creating targeted custom_NM_dispatcher_policy.pp policy package
rm tmp/custom_NM_dispatcher_policy.mod.fc tmp/custom_NM_dispatcher_policy.mod
```

Import custom policy module

`semodule -i custom_NM_dispatcher_policy.pp`

Confirm it was imported successfully

`semodule -l | grep custom`

Confirm policy actions

`sesearch -A -s NetworkManager_dispatcher_t -c service`

Test dispatcher script

`systemctl restart NetworkManager`

Check service logs

`journalctl -e --unit atd.service`

`journalctl -e --unit NetworkManager-dispatcher.service`

Check for SELinux failures

`ausearch -i | awk '/dispatcher/ && /atd/' | tail -5`

Get recommendations based on failures

`ausearch -i | awk '/dispatcher/ && /atd/' | tail -5 | audit2allow`

You can add the new recommendations from the above command to your custom_NM_dispatcher_policy.te file then repeat the steps to rebuild the .pp file and import it. That's what I did and eventually audit2allow ran out of recommendations but SELinux was still blocking my script.

---

Good luck, I hope this gives you a good head start!